# Push SQLite3 data to an ArrayList()

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I have a table of data with two cols "id" and "name". I'm trying to get all the names into an ArrayList from the database. What is the best way to make this call and create the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be something like this:

```
ArrayList myResults = new ArrayList(); 
Cursor c = db.query(...your Query Parameters here...);
c.moveToFirst();
while(!c.isAfterLast())
{
    myResults.add(c.getString(1));
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

Assuming that you select in your query the id and the name column in that order. Than the columnindex of name will be 1.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the while loop to go through the cursor contains and add each values to ArrayList.